# R: Trouble using SMOTE package "invalid 'labels'"

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-mining

Using SMOTE package from DMwR library. After loading the data frame, I try to perform sampling as follows :

```
crime_bal$target <- as.factor(crime_bal$target)
crime_bal <- SMOTE(target ~ .,crime_bal,perc.under = 200, perc.over = 100)
```

But it always ends up to this error :

```
Error in factor(newCases[, a], levels = 1:nlevels(data[, a]), labels = levels(data[,  : 
  invalid 'labels'; length 0 should be 1 or 2
In addition: Warning messages:
1: NAs introduced by coercion 
2: NAs introduced by coercion
```

Details of my dataset :

```
> summary(crime_bal)
     text               url            target  
 Length:6326        Length:6326        0:5994  
 Class :character   Class :character   1: 332  
 Mode  :character   Mode  :character
```

Why do I always end up with the error?

Answer (score 3):

From the error description, it looks like the code expects the data type of the column to be a 'factor' for a 'character' type column. Try casting the character column to factor using as.factor() before calling the SMOTE function.

```
crime_bal$text<-as.factor(crime_bal$text)
crime_bal$url<-as.factor(crime_bal$url)
```